# CGRectContainsPoint does not work on different views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgrect, uistackview

I am making a simple drag drop project. When I use `CGRectContainsPoint` to drag a view and drop on different view it works. But both of the view should be in a same view. Now let's say I have a view called "A" and it contains two views. One `UIView` and one `UIStackView`. If I drag a view inside of Stack View to UIView it does not drop. Simply `CGRectContainsPoint` does not work for dragging and dropping from different views. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Each view has its own coordinate system. Do you first convert the coordinates into a common system before using `CGRectContainsPoint`?

Comment: No I did not know that. How can I convert it?

Comment: There are several *convert* methods in UIView: see [Converting Between View Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW52)

Comment: Thank you for your help but can you please show me an example? It confuses me.

Comment: Show your code where `CGRectContainsPoint` is used. Then I can provide you a specific and hopefully helpful example.

Comment: if CGRectContainsPoint(self.dropAreaView1.frame, sender.view!.center) {}. "sender.view" is in a stack view and I am dragging/dropping sender view from stackview to dropAreaView1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As each view has it's own coordinate system, you have to convert all coordinates to the same coordinate system before you compare them (e.g. with `CGRectContainsPoint`. And you need to understand for each point or rectangle, in what coordinate system it is given. Apple always specifies it in the documentation.

As the common coordinate system either choose the one of a common parent or of the windows.

In your case, you compare whether the center of the view lies within the boundaries of another view. So pick a common parent view as the reference coordinate system, e.g. the view controllers main view:

In Swift:

```
let referenceView = self.view // assuming self is the view controller
let dropArea = referenceView.convertRect(self.dropAreaView1.bounds, fromView: self.dropAreaView1)
let center = referenceView.convertPoint(sender.view!.center, fromView: sender.view!.superview)
if CGRectContainsPoint(dropArea, center) {
   // do something
}
```

Note that `frame` specifies the boundary in the super view's coordinate system. Therefore, I've changed it to `bounds`, which specifies it in the view's onw coordinate system. Furthermore, `center` uses the super view's coordinate system. Therefore, I convert the point from the super view's to the reference view's system.

Comment: There is a new problem. It was used to be dropped on the center of the view. But not it is being dropped on random place on the view.

Comment: There are probably more coordinates involved than the ones you have shown in your tiny code snippets. Have you converted them to and from the correct coordinate system as well? You might want to start a new question with considerably more code.

Comment: if CGRectContainsPoint(dropArea, center) {}. I am using this piece of code to do drag drop action and it works flawlessly thanks to you. But now it does not not drop on the center of dropAreaView1. I did when i used frame instead of bounds. I think now this is causing the issue. referenceView.convertRect(self.dropAreaView1.bounds, fromView: self.dropAreaView1). But I may be wrong.